# An alternative to a regular poisson distribution for count data.

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution, fitting, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm trying to find out what distribution my empirical count data fits. Scores can run from 0-8 and I have ~360 observations. I've been using the `fitdistrplus` package and have tested a poisson distribution. The gof stats I got were:

```
Fitting of the distribution ' pois ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
       estimate Std. Error
lambda 4.490489 0.07811023
Loglikelihood:  -1571.578   AIC:  3145.155   BIC:  3149.756
```

I tried testing a negative binomial also but got this error message:

```
> fitnbinom <-fitdist(survival,"nbinom")
Warning messages:
1: In dnbinom(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L,  :
  NaNs produced
2: In dnbinom(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L,  :
  NaNs produced
```

I'm not sure the fit of the Poisson is that good so would like to test an alternative. Any suggestions? Also any help with the code for testing an alternative in `fitdistrplus` would be great - The examples provided in the vignette for count data test a Poisson and negative binomial but no others. I'm aware that you can test distributions provided in other packages but I haven't been able to work out how to do this.

[[image: Testing the poisson distribution]]

Comment: If it's bounded between 0 and 8, I wouldn't start with a Poisson. But why do you need to fit a distribution at all?

Comment: I need to test a mixed effects model and would like to know what distribution best fits the data so I can (attempt to) specify this in the model.

Comment: I don't see how the unconditional distribution of the response tells you what that should be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What would you suggest I do to check what distribution fits the data best?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because needs additional info and clarification for a good answer, but the OP hasn't been seen for years.